# Option for plain text mail notifications? (and spamassassin scoring due to HTML-only-ness)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, email

The mail notifications don't appear to have an option for plain-text rather than HTML, and they currently send *only* html parts (and hence hit the [MIME_HTML_ONLY](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/MIME_HTML_ONLY) rule in spamassassin's default settings).

Also, they flag the [MIME_QP_LONG_LINE](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/Rules/MIME_QP_LONG_LINE) spamassassin rule due to having lines longer than 76 characters.

Comment: good to know...

Comment: See also - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9711/why-is-email-from-so-marked-as-spam (completing the circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see the MIME_QP_LONG_LINE but I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

> edit: bug in the .NET framework! Doh!
>
> http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=156052

Basically, long URLs occurring anywhere in the text do not contain spaces and are not broken by the Quoted-Printable MIME algorithm.

I'm going to try switching to Base64 encoding for that portion of the email.

Update: we have switched to a [third party email component](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-email-components) recommended by our pals at [Doctype](http://doctype.com).

```
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 5.7.2.156
From: "Stack Overflow"
```

I can confirm that it "fixes" [the quoted-printable encoding bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=156052) in the .NET framework.

Comment: Comment attempt #3 :)

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1521.txt and look for the "Rule #5 (Soft Line Breaks)" section.

Comment: The soft line breaks should work OK with links too, but might rely on mail clients doing things properly and hence be less likely to work in practice.  (Base64 is probably a better choice because of this)

Comment: The most recent changes have fixed this, cheers!  :)

Comment: excellent, thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 1):

For me, SpamAssassin still triggers on `MIME_QP_LONG_LINE`:

```
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on <hostname>
X-Spam-Status: No, score=4.9 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_99,HTML_MESSAGE,
        MIME_QP_LONG_LINE,RDNS_NONE autolearn=no version=3.2.5
```

But because the `MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY` test isn't triggered anymore, the message is not considered spam.

Comment: Still hits the MIME_QP_LONG_LINE one for me too.

Comment: see my response, the LONG_LINE should now be fixed. Bug in .NET sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

We made some changes to address these two issues -- can you let us know if it's still an issue after tomorrow?

OK, we switched to Base64 encoding for the HTML part of the message, does this fix it?

We're also verifying our Reverse DNS (RDNS) settings, I could have sworn we had that set up correctly.

Comment: Still hitting MIME_QP_LONG_LINE for me, I'm afraid.

Comment: even with Base64 encoding? :)