# Why is email from SO marked as spam?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, email

The emails I receive from SO to notify me about answers are being marked as spam by my hosting provider. I cannot change the settings of the spamfilter and turning it off also seems like a bit too much...

These are the headers added by SpamAssassin:

```
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on <hostname>
X-Spam-Level: ******
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayesian spam probability is 99 to 100%
    *      [score: 1.0000]
    *  1.5 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  1.4 MIME_QP_LONG_LINE RAW: Quoted-printable line longer than 76 chars
    *  0.1 RDNS_NONE Delivered to trusted network by a host with no rDNS
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=6.5 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_99,HTML_MESSAGE,
    MIME_HTML_ONLY,MIME_QP_LONG_LINE,RDNS_NONE autolearn=no version=3.2.5
```

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks

---

The [changes made on Monday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9711/why-is-email-from-so-marked-as-spam/10237#10237) indeed solve the problem for me:

```
X-Spam-Level: ****
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on <hostname>
X-Spam-Status: No, score=4.9 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_99,HTML_MESSAGE,
        MIME_QP_LONG_LINE,RDNS_NONE autolearn=no version=3.2.5
```

Thanks you guys.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/option-for-plain-text-mail-notifications-and-spamassassin-scoring-due-to-html-o

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one when searching for similar questions.

Answer (score 4):

We made some changes tonight (Monday) to address these two issues. If you still see this by Friday, please let us know.

Update: we have switched to a [third party email component](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-email-components) recommended by our pals at [Doctype](http://doctype.com).

```
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 5.7.2.156
From: "Stack Overflow"
```

I can confirm that it "fixes" [the quoted-printable encoding bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=156052) in the .NET framework.

Comment: Thanks! I'll certainly will. (I've also convinced my hosting provider to put the Stack Overflow address in the whitelist. So I'll only be able to test this with mails from other domains...)

Answer (score 2):

Tell SpamAssissin that the e-mails aren't spam ;)

Though from the header information it seems that the HTML content and long line length are significant problems. If this e-mail contained code then there's probably nothing that Jeff can do to prevent the long line length.

Adding the sender to SpamAssissin's white list is probably the simplest thing to do and the one that's guaranteed to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any control over the SA from my hosting provider. But I'll certainly email my provider to add SO to the whitelist. Thanks.