# CSO emails contain extra ^M characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email

The verification email for CSO contains dodgy line endings, and looks like this in Mutt:

```
Thanks for registering with Stack Overflow Careers^M
^M
To ensure that potential employers can reach you via email, we need to confirm your email address. All it takes is a single click.^M
```

The whole message shows a ^M at the end of each line. The encoded form of the text/plain message looks like:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Thanks for registering with Stack Overflow Careers=0D =0A=0D=0ATo ensure=
 that potential employers can reach you via email, we need to confirm your=
 email address. All it takes is a single click.=0D =0A=0D=0AClick here to=
```

I'm pretty sure there isn't supposed to be that extra `=0D` in there (especially not with that extra space), and taking it out allows the message to render correctly in Mutt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to view the HTML version; the quoted-printable text/plain text stuff is only there as a weak fallback. (On Trilogy sites, the entirety of the text/plain is "view the html, please")

The QP bug is in the .NET framework mail classes.

[Option for plain text mail notifications? (and spamassassin scoring due to HTML-only-ness)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/option-for-plain-text-mail-notifications-and-spamassassin-scoring-due-to-html-o/11849#11849)

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=156052

Update: we have switched to a [third party email component](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-email-components) recommended by our pals at [Doctype](http://doctype.com).

```
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 5.7.2.156
From: "Stack Overflow"
```

I can confirm that it "fixes" [the quoted-printable encoding bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=156052) in the .NET framework.

Comment: Yes, the HTML one looks fine because whitespace is pretty much ignored by HTML renderers. I realise I'm in the minority here in using a text-only client, but SO may be one of the places with the *highest* proportion of users with non-HTML email clients. It seems pretty typical for Microsoft to get line endings wrong in email (they got it wrong everywhere else, after all).

Comment: believe me I am not happy about this, but writing our own mail classes from scratch (or adopting some third party code) is really painful.

Answer (score 4):

The notifications are [all about sharing the love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13014/notification-email-from-stackoverflow-contains-3-after-zip-code).

^M = Kissing you with sharp lips. Because it hurts when you lick a live CPU.

=0D = They're happy to help you, smile! (Their in ur newlinez fixin your ln breks)